# Which version of Entity Framework should I install?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, visual-studio-2012

I am working on a new project and want to use EF.  My last project used EF4 and it was installed as part of VS 2010 (or 8).

In this project, I am using VS 2012 which seems to want me to download EF instead.  No worries, I went to Extensions and Updates and entered Entity Framework.

There seem to be a large number of versions of EF 4, 5, and the beta of 6.

There doesn't seem to be a lot of information on how to choose the appropriate item to download.

I think I should use 5 since I have found that using beta versions sometimes cause delays, especially since they don't plan to release the RTM version until the next version of VS.

And then I need to know which file(s) to download.

My project is to write an app that will replace an existing app using an SQL database - so I need a data first implementation.

What I don't want to do is find out that I have spent tons of time trying to figure out a problem that is simply due to the fact that I didn't download the correct version....

Any suggestions on which version (EF 4,5, or 6) and which package for that version I should use?

Thanks!

Comment: EF 5 has some very nice and significant performance improvements - so I'd vote for EF5 for now. EF6 is still in beta/RC stage - a bit too early for my taste (for production use)

Comment: EF is a NuGet package which can be added to individual projects.  It isn't an extension.

Comment: Use the newest stable version, each new version fixes bugs and attempts to improve performance. But please avoid questions like this. This question is very broad and opinion based, and could lead to a long discussion instead of a succinct answer.

Comment: Travis - I know a question like this CAN be broad, but in many cases, it doesn't need to be so. I just am trying to get some idea of what to install so I can get some work done.

Comment: @JustMeToo - Also note that for discussion type questions, there are [chat rooms available at stackoverflow](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/).

Comment: @SLaks - So you are saying I should NOT use the Extenstions & Updates, but instead use NuGet to get EF? I will look into that, thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suggesting (like SLaks said) you should add EF through NuGet. I would start from here, if you're interested in detailed information about the capabilities that each version supports:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh551137%28VS.103%29.aspx

From this page there's a link to version history where you can read a summary about what's updated per version:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/data/jj574253

As for what I would do, choose the latest stable version. Not sure why, if there is a reason at all, EF community would release a stable version that's not better to it's predecessor.

Since you're maybe not to familiar with EF I also want to recommend:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/data/ef

P.S. Entity Framework 5.0 via NuGet:

http://nuget.org/packages/EntityFramework/5.0.0

Answer (score 2):

Since you are starting a new project, use the latest, non-beta version of the framework. You haven't specified any requirements that would tie you to an older version, and it doesn't appear you have an immediate need to explore the new features in the possibly unstable/unsupported beta version.

Answer (score 0):

SLacks pointed me in the right direction.  I had looked in Extensions (which has all kinds of EF add-ons) and what I needed was to use NuGet - which I have now done.

I know this is obvious to many, but for many, but I am use to installing an application and using the installer to add/remove features.  I am sure there are great reasons for having so many different ways to install features, but it does add a level of complexity that someone needs to learn - especially since each approach is implemented totally differently.

Thanks again.

Comment: You shouldn't comment on someone's answer using an answer. Instead, leave a comment on the answerer's accepted post.

Comment: The reason is that EF is not a feature; it's a library (= NuGet package) that you can use in a project.